# How to attach a function which is attaching another function to a yet non existent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

In my application, I am attaching functions to elements having the collection class:

```
$('.collection').each(initiateCollection);

function initiateCollection()
{
    var $container = $(this).children('div:first-child');

    if (!$container.data('is_collection'))
    {
        var $addButton = $container.children('.add_button').eq(0);

        $addButton.on('click', function(e) {
            addElement($container,index);
            count++;
            index++;
            showHeaders($container, count);
            correctSelect2Width($(this));
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        var count = $container.find('.child_collection').length;
        var index = $container.find('.child_collection').length;

        console.log(count);

        if (count == 0)
        {
            var $headers = $container.find('.headers').eq(0);
            var $headerPrototype = $($container.attr('data-header'));
            $headers.html($headerPrototype);
        }

        $container.on('click','.fmu_delete_button', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $row = $(this).closest('.row_to_delete');
            $row.next('.sibling_row_to_delete').remove();
            $row.next('.sibling_row_to_delete_2').remove();

            $row.remove();
            count--;
            showHeaders($container, count);
        });

        showHeaders($container, count);

        $container.data('is_collection', true);
    }
}
```

The issue is some collections are not yet loaded but I still need them to behave the same. I can't attach the function to a click and focus is not working either directly :

```
$('body').on('focus', '.collection', initiateCollection);
```

The previous line does not work cause my collections do not get the focus by default/immediately when added. I have explored other solutions without success (of course I can rebind from the code where I add a collection but it's not efficient).

What else can I try ?

Comment: can you put us up an example ?

Comment: why can't you just delegate the `add_button` events and not even worry about `focus`?

Comment: well, I'm doing more within the body of initiateCollection than just attaching events (counting subchilds, displaying things or not, calling other functions...). As for the example, I'd be just happy with the simple sample I put to work on a newly added '.collection'. what else do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple questions to answer but I think your problems could be handled by effectively using the second parameter in the `on()` function.

You should attach the click event to the container element that will contain the elements with the `.collection` class.

So instead of selecting through all the elements with the `.collection` class and binding the click event to the `.add_button` element, you could just bind it once to the parent of all the `.collection` elements and filter by `.add_button` like so:

```
$('.collection:eq(0)').parent().on('click', '.add_button:eq(0)', function(e) {
  // Logic for when button is clicked.
});
```

You then don't have to worry about calling some function to bind all your events when one of the `.collection` elements are added.

Of course, you could replace `$('.collection').parent()` with a selector that just targets that container without having to call `parent()`.

Comment: well, as per my comment, I am not interested in the click on the add_button but by the fact a new collection is added. I'm doing more than just listening to a click on the add_button.

Comment: By looking at your code, all your logic is inside the click event on your `.add_button` element. You might have to post more of your code on here that way we can see what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I just added the whole code: so indeed, there is a lot of logic outside of this add_button element. thanks for your time